# Smarty variables, assigning javascript function as value does not work (upgrading from v2 to v3)

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I have the following code, that works for smarty 2.x

```
{assign var=somename value=jsFunction($frontItemKey);}
```

but smarty v3 throws an error:

```
unknown function "jsFunction"
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve, to assign a string "jsFunction($frontItemKey)" to a variable? Or to put there the return value of some function?

In first case, which seems more possible, I think you just need should handle it as a string, because Smarty is definitely trying to call a function by that name and can't find it.
If you want a string like "jsFunction(VALUE)" where value is the $frontItemKey value, you should concatenate it.

In second case, if Smarty2 puts some value there, I would first check your Smarty2 source code, probably somebody changed it and added this function. Take a look at the Smarty libs folder.

Comment: note that smarty3 does no longer require you to use the assign. You could just say {$somename = "jsFunction($frontItemKey);"}